# Normalize complex eigenvectors with Sympy

Tags: sympy, complex-numbers, eigenvector

I'm solving a time dependent complex eigenvalue problem where my matrix is hermitian. My problem is that for some reason I can't normalize the eigenvectors. This is one example using one of the eigenvectors (where `r_1` is an real function of `t`)

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.physics.quantum.dagger import Dagger
t= sp.symbols(r't , real=True)
r = sp.symbols(r'r_1, real=True)

v = ...
print(repr(v))
```

The eigenvector is:

```
Matrix([
[                                   0],
[r_1**2/(4*t**3 - 8*t**2 + 4*t) - 1/t],
[                      -r_1/(2*t - 2)],
[                                   0],
[                                   1],
[                                   0],
[                                   0],
[                                   0]])
```

Calculating the norm:

```
a = Dagger(v)*v
a[0]
```

gives

[image]

So the normalized vector is:

```
v_N = v/sp.sqrt(a[0])
v_N
```

[image]

Testing the normalization gives:

```
Dagger(v_N)*v_N
```

[image]

Or :

```
sp.simplify(Dagger(v_N)*v_N)
```

[image]

That is different than 1

Comment: With `simplify(vn.dot(vn))` I get 1.